Long Table Fit Within Margins in LaTeX
My table is currently exceeding the margins and I'm looking for suggestions to improve it. Below are my code and the resulting output.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, a4paper]{geometry} % Sets the margin to 2cm and paper size to A4
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better quality table lines
\usepackage{longtable} % Allows tables to span multiple pages if necessary

\begin{document}

\section*{Appendix} % Creates a non-numbered section for the Appendix



\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small % Makes the text smaller
\caption{Summary of Variables, Descriptions, Measurements, and Sources}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllp{5cm}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Measurement} & \textbf{Source} \\
\midrule
EP1 & Energy poverty & Access to electricity (\% of the population) & WDI \\
EP2 & Energy poverty & Access to clean fuels and technologies for cooking & WDI \\
EP3 & Energy poverty & Urban population with access to electricity & WDI \\
EP4 & Energy poverty & Rural population with access to electricity & WDI \\
EP & Energy poverty & Composite Index & Author's calculation \\
Urb & Urbanization & Urban population (\% of total population) & WDI \\
Gdp & Gross domestic product & Log GDP per capita (constant 2010 USD) & WDI \\
Pop & Population & Population growth rate & WDI \\
Transp & Transport Composite Index & Total Paved Roads (km per 10,000 inhabitants); Total Road Network in Km (per km2 of exploitable land area) & AfDB \\
Elec & Electricity Composite Index & Total electricity production of a given country, including the energy imported from abroad & AfDB \\
ICT & ICT Composite Index & Total Phone Subscriptions (per 100 inhabitants); Number of Internet Users (per 100 inhabitants); Fixed Broadband Internet Subscribers (per 100 inhabitants) & AfDB \\
WSS & WSS Composite Index & Improved Water Source (\% of population with access); Improved sanitation facilities (\% of population with access) & AfDB \\
AIDI & Africa Infrastructure Development Index & Composite Index is computed using the sub-indexes of the four components: Electricity, Water, Sanitation and ICT subscriptions, and paved roads. & AfDB \\
Sanitation & Sanitation & Percent of population with access to improved sanitation & WDI \\
Internet & Telecommunication & Secure internet per million people and telephone faults per 100 mainlines & WDI \\
Electric power & Power & Electric power transmission and distribution losses (\% of output) & WDI \\
Transport & Transport & Share of paved roads in total roads & WDI \\
Water & Water & Percent of population with access to improved water source & WDI \\
RE1 & Renewable electricity output & Renewable electricity output (\% of total electricity output) & WDI \\
RE2 & Electricity production from renewable sources & Electricity production from renewable sources, excluding hydroelectric (kWh) & WDI \\
Inequality & Income inequality & Income inequality refers to the disparity in the distribution of income within a given population & WIID \\
LEGATUM & Legatum Prosperity Index & Composite index that measures the level of prosperity and well-being in different countries around the world. & Legatum Institute \\
SPI & Social Progress Index & Composite indicator that assesses the social well-being and progress of societies across several key dimensions. & Social Progress Imperative \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]




Your table is too wide because you're not allowing automatic linebreaking in columns 2 and 3 and because you've set a needlessly large value for the width of the 4th column. Try loading the tabularx package and replacing \begin{tabular}{@{} lll p{5cm} @{}} with \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l p{3.7cm} X p{1.7cm}@{}}. And, of course, do replace \end{tabular} with \end{tabularx}.

You could use fixed width columns for the second and third column to enable line breaks.
Here an example using the tabularray package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, a4paper]{geometry} % Sets the margin to 2cm 

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section*{Appendix} % Creates a non-numbered section for the Appendix

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={Summary of Variables, Descriptions, Measurements, and Sources}
]{
  colspec={@{}lX[0.8,halign=l]X[2.2]X[0.5,halign=l]@{}}
}
\toprule
\textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Measurement} & \textbf{Source} \\
\midrule
EP1 & Energy poverty & Access to electricity (\% of the population) & WDI \\
EP2 & Energy poverty & Access to clean fuels and technologies for cooking & WDI \\
EP3 & Energy poverty & Urban population with access to electricity & WDI \\
EP4 & Energy poverty & Rural population with access to electricity & WDI \\
EP & Energy poverty & Composite Index & Author's calculation \\
Urb & Urbanization & Urban population (\% of total population) & WDI \\
Gdp & Gross domestic product & Log GDP per capita (constant 2010 USD) & WDI \\
Pop & Population & Population growth rate & WDI \\
Transp & Transport Composite Index & Total Paved Roads (km per 10,000 inhabitants); Total Road Network in Km (per km2 of exploitable land area) & AfDB \\
Elec & Electricity Composite Index & Total electricity production of a given country, including the energy imported from abroad & AfDB \\
ICT & ICT Composite Index & Total Phone Subscriptions (per 100 inhabitants); Number of Internet Users (per 100 inhabitants); Fixed Broadband Internet Subscribers (per 100 inhabitants) & AfDB \\
WSS & WSS Composite Index & Improved Water Source (\% of population with access); Improved sanitation facilities (\% of population with access) & AfDB \\
AIDI & Africa Infrastructure Development Index & Composite Index is computed using the sub-indexes of the four components: Electricity, Water, Sanitation and ICT subscriptions, and paved roads. & AfDB \\
Sanitation & Sanitation & Percent of population with access to improved sanitation & WDI \\
Internet & Telecommunication & Secure internet per million people and telephone faults per 100 mainlines & WDI \\
Electric power & Power & Electric power transmission and distribution losses (\% of output) & WDI \\
Transport & Transport & Share of paved roads in total roads & WDI \\
Water & Water & Percent of population with access to improved water source & WDI \\
RE1 & Renewable electricity output & Renewable electricity output (\% of total electricity output) & WDI \\
RE2 & Electricity production from renewable sources & Electricity production from renewable sources, excluding hydroelectric (kWh) & WDI \\
Inequality & Income inequality & Income inequality refers to the disparity in the distribution of income within a given population & WIID \\
LEGATUM & Legatum Prosperity Index & Composite index that measures the level of prosperity and well-being in different countries around the world. & Legatum Institute \\
SPI & Social Progress Index & Composite indicator that assesses the social well-being and progress of societies across several key dimensions. & Social Progress Imperative \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}


